# Might a previously administered MPSV4 vaccine react with a newly administered MCV-4 vaccine?

Tags: vaccination

This is a hypothetical situation.

Meningococcal polysaccharide vaccine (MPSV4) is a vaccine against Neisseria meningitidis. 
MCV4 is a conjugate vaccine.

I would like to know if the polysaccharide base could interact with the conjugate base.
I think they would not act like booster doses and that the efficacy of the conjugate vaccine would be decreased, due to the lifelong effects of MPSV4.

**Might MPSV4's polysaccharide base interact with MCV4's conjugate base, and if so, what might be the mechanism?**